# how to add new table to existing entity model without losing any customisation to model?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I want to add a new table in my existing entity data model without using the option update from database. Because in this case i loss existing modification like inheritance and entity names.

Comment: False premise. Using "Update from database" does *not* cause inheritance or custom names to be lost.

Answer (score 1):

Right click, add new entity, and then manually fill out the Property and Navigation properties.  Then look for a tab ( usually at the bottom ) called mapping details, thats where you specify how the columns map up.

Comment: I need to add a entity with a new table, that is not still map in the model. And if i update from database, existing changes can be loss.